# Issuing a lock and timeout value on a Oracle database table

Tags: database, oracle, locking

I have two applications accessing the same table. I only want one app accessing the table at any time.

Is it possible to issue a lock at the start of a method and remove the lock at the end?
Also, in case the app dies, can we set a timeout value on the lock?

Overview of the Java method:

```
//read the table...
//do something with the data
//update the table
return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simplest way, is probably to issue a 'select for update' statement on a row in a lock table, eg:

```
create table app_lock ( application_name varchar2(100) not null);

insert into app_lock values ('myapp');

commit;

select application_name from app_lock where application_name = 'myapp' for update;
```

Then, if another session attempts to run the same SQL statement, it will block until the first session frees the lock. Or you can specify a timeout value. For example to timeout after 10 seconds:

```
select application_name from app_lock where application_name = 'myapp' for update wait 10;
```

The lock is freed by either issuing a commit or rollback, or in the event that the application dies, it will disconnect from Oracle and rollback freeing the lock too.

Another option is to lock the table:

```
lock table mytable in exclusive mode;
```

Again, this lock is held until your session commits, rolls back or disconnects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean the lock will only be free when I called commit after the select statement?

Comment: I don't think that the exclusive lock on the table should be considered an option as it doesn't block readers.

Comment: @xcoder - yes, for most things related to locking in Oracle issuing a commit or rollback (ie ending the transaction) will free the lock.

Comment: @sstan - I hadn't though about blocking readers of the table, only blocking concurrent writers. Technically there nothing stopping someone working around the lock row outside the application too. The lock table row is kind of like a lock file - if you code another application that doesn't use the lock row correctly, it can still get in and change the data!

Comment: @Stephen: Agreed. It's just that for your `app_lock` option, you make it very clear that the apps need to do a `select for update`.  However, the way you present the exclusive lock option, it makes it sound like nothing special is needed other than the lock itself, which can give the wrong impression.  To make it a viable option to present, you would have to be clearer about what the app's responsibility is, if that option is used.

Comment: @sstan - makes sense. In some ways the lock table option is safer if you want to protect from concurrent updates. If the application has the exclusive lock, nobody can modify the table from any application or database connection. Like with many of these things, it depends ...  :-)